# Why is the value of `%profile%` not immediately available after `set /P profile="sas-admin profile:"`?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I have a batch (`*.bat`) file that should login to a server.
These are a few of the lines in it:

```
set /P token_user=":     SAS token account (srvglobalff...) :"
echo token user is %token_user%

set /p proceed="Proceed with these parameters? (Execute, Cancel) :"
rem If "Execute" selected, apply all
if /i %proceed:~0,1%==E (
    set /P profile="sas-admin profile:"
    echo profile is %profile%, token_user_is %token_user%
    do_stuff --profile %profile% 
    more_stuff --account %token_user%
```

If I run this with and enter `token_1` and `profile_1`, it echos

```
profile is , token_user_is token_1
```

If I run it again with and enter `token_2` and `profile_2`, it echos

```
profile is profile_1, token_user_is token_2
```

What explains this and how do I cure it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add nore details: What exactly means "it runs without a `profile`" or "it runs without `profile_1` and `token_2`"? Please show the input you use, the output you get and the expected output.

Comment: You need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `echo profile is !profile!, token_user_is !token_user!`

Comment: That's why I did edit it, but you did not notice; (Meanwhile I improved the markdown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not fully clear and should be improved.

The actual value of the variable will have changed immediately after the `set` command. The problem results from the point in time when CMD expands the variables while executing the script.

When Windows CMD processes this `if` statement

```
if /i %proceed:~0,1%==E (
    set /P profile="sas-admin profile:"
    echo profile is %profile%, token_user_is %token_user%
    do_stuff --profile %profile% 
    more_stuff --account %token_user%
)
```

it will expand all variables before executing the complete statement, so for example the line

```
echo profile is %profile%, token_user_is %token_user%
```

will use the values of `profile` and `token_user` that were defined before the `if` statement.

Your code requires to expand `%profile%` in the `echo` command with the value entered just before at `set /P profile=...` inside the same `if` statement. For this you need delayed expansion using `!profile!` instead of `%profile%`. To use delayed expansion it must be enabled with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

**Modified script**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /P token_user=":     SAS token account (srvglobalff...) :"
echo token user is %token_user%

set /p proceed="Proceed with these parameters? (Execute, Cancel) :"
rem If "Execute" selected, apply all
if /i %proceed:~0,1%==E (
    set /P profile="sas-admin profile:"
    echo profile is !profile!, token_user is %token_user%
    do_stuff --profile !profile! 
    more_stuff --account %token_user%
)
```

In the example from the question, delayed expansion is only necessary for `profile`. If you don't want to change the value of `token_user` inside the `if` statement, you don't need delayed expansion (`!token_user!`) for this variable, but it would also work with

```
    echo profile is !profile!, token_user is !token_user!
```